# Stand alone ParametricPlot3D image file for others' 3D viewing

Tags: display

I wish to show a ParametricPlot3D image sharing only the image part that is made available for mouse rotation view for any-ViewPoints by viewers other than the code-maker?

Is it possible to delink the code which was used to create the image at first and later on dump all image digital info of  (point/line/surface) in a separate input part file for display?

Advantage could be code protection and code size reduction.

Comment: You can deploy output as .cdf, but then others need to fetch FreePlayer.

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CDFDeploy.html